# Unknown compiler version while compiling Boost with MSVC 14.0 (VS 2015)

Tags: c++, boost, visual-studio-2015

I get "Unknown compiler version - please run configure tests and report the results" while attempting to compile Boost library on my computer.
I have most recent Boost (as of date of the post) - 1.58.0.
Doesn't Boost support MSVC 14.0, yet? How do I "run the configure tests"?

[image: Screenshots].

Comment: What does the Boost documentation say about that?

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti: How do I undefine "BOOST_ASSERT_CONFIG"? You may want to see screenshots. I'm not yet even in Visual Studio project. I want to compile lib file first.... Also.. -1? At least explain why.

Comment: @KABoissonneault To answer your question, docs, says: "The library was successfully built and tested on the following platforms: ... MSVC 9.0 and newer". I don't get it..

Comment: At this point, I'd consider contacting the Boost people directly. They might have a better answer

Comment: @OmegaExtern well, they obviously meant "MSVC 9.0 and newer *available by the date of 1.58 release*".

Comment: Since when Boost is a C library?

Comment: Old question by now, but boost 1.59.0 has official support for VS 2015.

Comment: If you use NuGet you can easily upgrade to the newest version of boost hat will works with your compiler.

Comment: Still an issue with Boost 1.65/VS2017

Answer (score 70, accepted):

Latest (at the time of posting this answer)  **Boost 1.58** does support **MSVC 14.0 Preview** which was the latest MS compiler at the time of Boost 1.58 release.
Now, the latest version of **Visual Studio** is **2015 RC** which isn't covered in the boost 1.58 config file.

To stop Boost 1.58 complaining about unknown compiler version edit `boost/config/compiler/visualc.hpp` and replace:

```
// last known and checked version is 19.00.22129 (VC14 Preview):
#if (_MSC_VER > 1800 && _MSC_FULL_VER > 190022310)
```

with:

```
// last known and checked version is 19.00.22816 (VC++ 2015 RC):
#if (_MSC_VER > 1800 && _MSC_FULL_VER > 190022816)
```

which you can find is already done in boost repo [here](https://github.com/boostorg/config/pull/60/files) for upcoming Boost 1.59 release.

***Update***: For **Visual Studio 2015 RTM** set it to:

```
// last known and checked version is 19.00.23026 (VC++ 2015):
#if (_MSC_VER > 1800 && _MSC_FULL_VER > 190023026)
```

***Update2***: For **Visual Studio 2015 Update 1** set it to:

```
// last known and checked version is 19.00.23506 (VC++ 2015 Update 1):
#if (_MSC_VER > 1800 && _MSC_FULL_VER > 190023506)
```

---

Also if you have previously been running Boost.Build on `toolset=msvc-14.0` then delete from `C:\Users\<name>\AppData\Local\Temp` the following cached files:

```
b2_msvc_14.0_vcvarsall_x86.cmd 
b2_msvc_14.0_vcvarsall_x86_amd64.cmd 
b2_msvc_14.0_vcvarsall_x86_arm.cmd
```

More about that [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/boost-devel-archive/5GNGMz8JC0w).

***Update3***
For future reference, in your Visual Studio Tools Command Prompt run the command `cl /Bv` to see your version numbers (the parameters are case sensitive).

Mine outputs the following:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Preview\Professional\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.11.25503\bin\HostX64\x64\cl.exe:        Version 19.11.25506.0
 C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Preview\Professional\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.11.25503\bin\HostX64\x64\c1.dll:        Version 19.11.25506.0
 C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Preview\Professional\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.11.25503\bin\HostX64\x64\c1xx.dll:      Version 19.11.25506.0
 C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Preview\Professional\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.11.25503\bin\HostX64\x64\c2.dll:        Version 19.11.25506.0
 C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Preview\Professional\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.11.25503\bin\HostX64\x64\link.exe:      Version 14.11.25506.0
 C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Preview\Professional\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.11.25503\bin\HostX64\x64\mspdb140.dll:  Version 14.11.25506.0
 C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Preview\Professional\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.11.25503\bin\HostX64\x64\1033\clui.dll: Version 19.11.25506.0
```

From this you can deduce the `_MSC_VER` is 1911 (from the text "Version 19.11") and the `_MSC_FULL_VER` is 191125506.

Comment: At the end - builded successfully. Though, thanks for your information.

Comment: And for the next VS updates, magic numbers can be get by `cl` command in `Visual Studio Command Prompt (2015)`

Answer (score 38):

Edit `boost/config/compiler/visualc.hpp` and replace the test about the last known and checked version with one of the following line:

1) If you want to deactivate completely the version check:

```
#if 0
```

2) If you want to check the major version only (select a single line):

```
#if (_MSC_VER > 1900) // Visual Studio 2015
#if (_MSC_VER > 1911) // Visual Studio 2017 15.0, 15.1 and 15.2
#if (_MSC_VER > 1911) // Visual Studio 2017 15.3 and 15.4
#if (_MSC_VER > 1912) // Visual Studio 2017 15.5
#if (_MSC_VER > 1913) // Visual Studio 2017 15.6
#if (_MSC_VER > 1914) // Visual Studio 2017 15.7
#if (_MSC_VER > 1915) // Visual Studio 2017 15.8
#if (_MSC_VER > 1916) // Visual Studio 2017 15.9
#if (_MSC_VER > 1920) // Visual Studio 2019 16.0
```

3) If you want to check both the major and minor version (select a single line):

```
#if (_MSC_VER > 1900 && _MSC_FULL_VER > 190023506) // Visual Studio 2015 Update 1
#if (_MSC_VER > 1900 && _MSC_FULL_VER > 190023918) // Visual Studio 2015 Update 2
#if (_MSC_VER > 1900 && _MSC_FULL_VER > 190023918) // Visual Studio 2015 Update 3
#if (_MSC_VER > 1910 && _MSC_FULL_VER > 191025017) // Visual Studio 2017 15.0, 15.1 and 15.2
#if (_MSC_VER > 1911 && _MSC_FULL_VER > 191125542) // Visual Studio 2017 15.3 and 15.4
#if (_MSC_VER > 1912 && _MSC_FULL_VER > 191225835) // Visual Studio 2017 15.5
#if (_MSC_VER > 1913 && _MSC_FULL_VER > 191326132) // Visual Studio 2017 15.6
#if (_MSC_VER > 1914 && _MSC_FULL_VER > 191426433) // Visual Studio 2017 15.7
#if (_MSC_VER > 1915 && _MSC_FULL_VER > 191526726) // Visual Studio 2017 15.8
#if (_MSC_VER > 1916 && _MSC_FULL_VER > 191627030) // Visual Studio 2017 15.9
#if (_MSC_VER > 1920 && _MSC_FULL_VER > 192027508) // Visual Studio 2019 16.0
```

Comment: Visual Studio 2017: `#if (_MSC_VER > 1910 && _MSC_FULL_VER > 191025017)`

Comment: VS2015U3 is 190024215

Comment: Now the latest release VS 2017 full version ends on 7 (not 6), but in boost 1.65 only _MSC_VER is used, so if you only update that part it works fine.

Comment: This is strange, I just updated and the full version on my side is still 191125506

Comment: VS2017 v15.5.1 _MSC_VER=1912 _MSC_FULL_VER=191225830

Comment: BTW: `_MSC_FULL_VER=191426433` is Visual Studio 2017 version 15.7.5.
https://dev.to/yumetodo/list-of-mscver-and-mscfullver-8nd

Answer (score 5):

In general, open `boost/config/compiler/visualc.hpp` and hover the mouse over `_MSC_FULL_VER` to see the version installed on your environment.

Answer (score 4):

Now using the fully released version of msvc-14.0 (Visual Studio 2015), you can use this:

```
#if (_MSC_VER > 1800 && _MSC_FULL_VER > 190023026)
```

Is there any danger is this?  Should we instead wait for the next release of Boost that has been officially edited to have this value?

Answer (score -1):

I have tried the following code in Ogre 1.9 - Visual Studio 2015.

Last known and checked version is 19.00.23506 (VC++ 2015 Update 1)

`if (_MSC_VER > 1800 && _MSC_FULL_VER > 190023506)`