# Building Boost with VS2015

Tags: visual-c++, boost, visual-studio-2015

I am trying to update from VS2013->VS2015, and to do that I need to rebuild my boost library files using VS2015. I grabbed the latest boost (1.58). By default boost is trying to build with VS2013. I tried to invoke bjam with `toolset=msvc-14.0` but this did not work, as it keeps saying:

> 'cl' is not a recognized as an internal or external command

I guess it doesn't know where VS2015 is located? Does anyone know what I need to change to get boost to build with VS2015?

Comment: Have you tried running the command from a VS2015 command prompt?

Comment: Once you sort out your building you are very likely going to face "unknown compiler version" error, then follow my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30959156/4899330)

Answer (score 0):

[BlueGo](https://bitbucket.org/Vertexwahn/bluego) is a tool which builds Boost using Visual Studio 2010/12/13/15. You just have to start the application, select your configuration and hit the Build button- everything else works automatically. The application downloads the library, extracts it and builds it. Can be downloaded from [here](https://bitbucket.org/Vertexwahn/bluego/downloads).

Screenshot of BlueGo:
[image: Screenshot of BlueGo]

You also need to install **Common Tools for Visual C++ 2015** as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31566807/how-to-build-boost-version-1-58-0-using-visual-studio-2015-enterprise).

Prebuild boost libraries for VS2015 can be found [here](https://sourceforge.net/projects/boost/files/boost-binaries/). Those seem to be very carefully maintained.