# Unknown compiler version while compiling with Boost on MSVC 15.3.3 (VS 2017)

Tags: boost, visual-studio-2017

There is a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30760889/unknown-compiler-version-while-compiling-boost-with-msvc-14-0-vs-2015/34055064#34055064) so the answer to this one might be able to be merged or something.

I am using the latest Visual Studio 2017 build and when I compile with Boost libraries I get a warning. The code raising the warning:

```
//
// last known and checked version is 19.10.25017 (VC++ 2017):
#if (_MSC_VER > 1910)
#  if defined(BOOST_ASSERT_CONFIG)
#     error "Unknown compiler version - please run the configure tests and report the results"
#  else
#     pragma message("Unknown compiler version - please run the configure tests and report the results")
#  endif
#endif
```

On my computer `_MSC_VER` is `1911`. I am using the latest **1.65** version of **Boost**. Is this easily fixable?

Thanks.

Comment: Based on the question you refer to, I'd guess it's as easy as changing the 1910 to 1911?

Comment: @DanMašek Thanks. I would like to know though if making such assumptions to changing the code is bypassing any review work that needs to be made to Boost officially?

Comment: Here's a patch that was already merged into trunk: https://github.com/boostorg/config/pull/179

Comment: @DanMašek Cool! I also see that 1.65.1 is due for release in the next couple of days ... :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to let everyone know that the latest version **1.65.1** resolves this issue:

http://www.boost.org/users/history/version_1_65_1.html